# How to insert 1 million data less 5 minute in pl/sql oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

Need to insert large amount of records within 5 minutes time. Here is the pl/SQL I have tried,

```
procedure insert_student(name_      in varchar2,
                         address_   in varchar2,
                         phone_     in varchar2,
                         class_     in varchar2) is                                  

        begin

          insert into student.student_scholarship(name, address,
          phone, class, date)
          values (name_, address_, phone_, class_, sysdate)
          );
        commit;                
end insert_student;
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? do you have any benchmark?

Comment: Regardless of your hardware，5 minute is a long time.use batch insert and only commite once.

Comment: how is this procedure being called ? how is the data being passed to the procedure ?

Comment: What is your data source ? Ex. are you trying to import it from a file ?

Comment: for huge datasets its preferred to use INSERT AS SELECT, or FORALL. (you can hint the INSERT with the APPEND hint)

Comment: Specify your data source, because if you don't, you might get a lot of different and irrelevant answers. What you need is a BULK operation of some kind if you want to achieve performance. Basically PL/SQL stores the data in RAM and uses that as a quick way of inserting rows in bulk. Take a look at it, try it yourself and come up with an example here.

Comment: my friend for these things is good ol' sqlload https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm

Comment: Is your million rows to be inserted coming from another table, a flat file, another DB ? The answer that works for you will depend on the data source. A million in 5 minutes should not be too challenging.

Answer (score 1):

For the following simulation, we have {A} generated a STUDENT table, containing 1,000,000 rows, populated with random strings.  Since you have not told us *where* you are loading the data from, we have {B} exported/unloaded the data to a CSV file, and {C} used the data via an EXTERNAL table, which we then utilise for the various INSERT techniques. (all done with Oracle 12c, "Developer Days" VM)

{A} "Source table"

```
create table student ( name, address, phone, sclass )
as
select 
  dbms_random.string( 'x', 25 )
, dbms_random.string( 'x', 40 )
, dbms_random.string( 'x', 20 )
, dbms_random.string( 'x', 5 )
from dual
connect by level <= 1000000 ;
-- Elapsed: 00:03:25.032

-- quick check
select count(*) from student ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1000000
```

{B} write 1,000,000 rows into a CSV file

```
set term off
set feed off
set sqlformat csv
spool /home/oracle/data_out/out.csv
select /*+ parallel */* from student ;
spool off
```

{C} external table

```
create table external_ ( 
  name    varchar2( 4000 )
, address varchar2( 4000 )
, phone   varchar2( 4000 )
, sclass  varchar2( 4000 )
) 
organization external (
  type oracle_loader 
  default directory external_tables
  access parameters 
  ( 
     records field names all files
     fields CSV with embedded record terminators
  ) 
  location 
  (
    'out.csv'
  ) 
)
/
-- quick check
SQL> select count(*) from external_ ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1000000
```

"destination" table

```
create table scholarship (
  name    varchar2( 25 )
, address varchar2( 40 )
, phone   varchar2( 20 )
, sclass   varchar2( 5 )
, sdate   date default sysdate
);
```

When INSERTing 1,000,000 rows, using pure SQL, we got the following times (test run 3 times, the SCHOLARSHIP table was DROPped in between tests).

```
-- {1}  SQL: INSERT ... SELECT ...
insert into scholarship ( name, address, phone, sclass ) 
select name, address, phone, sclass from external_ ;

-- 1,000,000 rows inserted.
-- Elapsed: 00:00:02.607
-- Elapsed: 00:00:02.300
-- Elapsed: 00:00:02.473
```

Probably the worst option is this: using PL/SQL and a CURSOR FOR LOOP (test run 3 times, SCHOLARSHIP dropped in between tests).

```
--{2}  PL/SQL: use a cursor for loop ("slow by slow")
begin
  for rec_ in ( select * from external_ )
  loop
    insert into scholarship ( name, address, phone, sclass )
    values ( rec_.name, rec_.address, rec_.phone, rec_.sclass ) ;
  end loop ;
  commit ;
end ;
/

-- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
-- Elapsed: 00:00:24.777
-- Elapsed: 00:00:22.700
-- Elapsed: 00:00:24.291
```

A bit better: use PL/SQL's bulk operations (again with "elapsed times" for 3 test runs).

```
--{3}  PL/SQL: use BULK COLLECT and FORALL (no need to re-compile in between tests)
create or replace procedure insert_students is
  type student_t is table of external_%rowtype index by pls_integer ;
  lstudents student_t ;
begin
  select * bulk collect into lstudents from external_  ;
  forall i in 1.. lstudents.count
    insert into scholarship ( name, address, phone, sclass )
    values ( lstudents( i ).name, lstudents( i ).address, lstudents( i ).phone, lstudents( i ).sclass  );
end ;
/

begin
  insert_students ;
  commit ;
end ;
/

-- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
-- Elapsed: 00:00:08.706
-- Elapsed: 00:00:06.762
-- Elapsed: 00:00:04.989
```

As many people will tell you: use SQL (only) whenever possible.  Now, you can probably see that your initial approach - using a procedure with parameters, and performing only one INSERT at a time - may not be the best technique for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FORALL` statement. It is much faster than saving records one by one OR with use of `FOR` loop because it doesn't change context between PL/SQL and SQL every time PL/SQL processor passes through SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    id NUMBER(19,0),
    address VARCHAR2(300)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack AS
TYPE t_students IS TABLE OF students%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE insert_students( l_students IN t_students);

END pack;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack AS

PROCEDURE insert_students( l_students IN t_students) AS
    BEGIN
      FORALL i IN 1..l_students.COUNT
      INSERT INTO students VALUES (l_students(i).id, l_students(i).address);
    END;
END pack;
/
```

Comment: FORALL is faster than single calls but probably not faster than pure SQL `insert into ... select * from ...`. The OP has provided no details regarding the source of their input data so we have no reason to suppose they need any PL/SQL at all.